# A drawing canvas/surface that will look same in any environment?

Tags: cross-platform, drawing, surface

You develop an application on windows. And deploy it on windows machines. You find it looks neat, since the windows gui system renders quite well. If you want the same app to run under linux or unix platforms they look different. Because the UI system they use might be different. Is there any standard to how for e.g. buttons can look or feel in an application which runs on multiple os platforms? The button should look the same on windows and linux. Are projects actually striving for such a standard?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much every project which has tried has utterly failed, or been universally derided for attempting it (java, adobe, openstep, etc.)

Imagine a furniture designer trying to create a chair that looks good in a mcdonalds, and in an upscale restaurant. It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that your solution *should* look/behave the same regardless of the platform it's deployed on.

Each platform has its own well-designed idioms and behaviours that its users are used to. If your application cooperates with the underlying system and acts in the required way on each, then your users are going to be a lot more comfortable with using your software.